# why closest is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I was trying to develop the FAQ panel in my page, when I am trying to use the `closest()` function, it is not working properly, am I doing any mistake, can anyone help me out in this.

heres the code which I wrote

```js
$('.faqQuestion').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent('.faqData').find('.open').removeClass('open');
  $(this).closest('.faqQuestion').addClass("open");

})
```

```css
.closed{
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: absolute;
}
.open{
 height: auto;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
}

.faqQuestion{
 display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.faqContent.open{
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqData clearfix">
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is a Virtual Assistant (VA)?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is the COST OF OUR SERVICES?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    Why work with our VA?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

## zeasts

Comment: because it is working. you just don't understand it's purpose.

Comment: *"it is not working properly"* is not a useful problem description. What do you want to do and what does actually happen? *"develop the FAQ panel"* doesn't tell us what you expect the code to do.

Comment: when I click on any `faqQuestion`, the `faqContent` should open and if other `faqContent` is opened, that should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

> when I click on any faqQuestion, the faqContent should open and if other faqContent is opened, that should be closed.

Keep it simple:

```
$('.faqQuestion').on('click', function(){
  $('.faqContent').removeClass('open') // close all
  $(this).next('.faqContent').addClass('open') // open the one immediately following what was clicked
})
```

(It's not clear to me whether you also need to set/remove the .closed class shown in your css; if so you would do that the same way: `.addClass('open').removeClass('closed')` and vice-versa).

Answer (score 2):

Use  `$(this).next('.faqContent').addClass("open");`

```js
$('.faqQuestion').on('click', function(){

  $(this).parent('.faqData').find('.open').removeClass('open').addClass('open');
  $(this).next('.faqContent').addClass("open");
  

})
```

```css
.closed{
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: absolute;
}
.open{
 height: auto;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.faqQuestion{
   display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.faqContent.open{
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqData clearfix">
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is a Virtual Assistant (VA)?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is the COST OF OUR SERVICES?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    Why work with our VA?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the div that follows the question (faqContent), so `.closest()`, which traverses up the DOM, isn't what you want. Instead use `.next()`

```
$(this).next().addClass("open");
```

```js
$('.faqQuestion').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent('.faqData').find('.open').removeClass('open');
  $(this).next().addClass("open");
})
```

```css
.closed{
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: absolute;
}
.open{
 height: auto;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
}

.faqQuestion{
 display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.faqContent.open{
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqData clearfix">
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is a Virtual Assistant (VA)?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is the COST OF OUR SERVICES?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    Why work with our VA?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is using to get closest ancestor element which. In your case use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method since you want to the sibling which is immediately after the element.

```js
$('.faqQuestion').on('click', function(){
 // remove `open` class and add `closed` class from all elements
  $('.faqContent').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
  // add `open` class and remove `closed` class from adjuscent sibling
  $(this).next().addClass("open").removeClass('closed');
})
```

```css
.closed{
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: absolute;
}
.open{
 height: auto;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
}

.faqQuestion{
 display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.faqContent.open{
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqData clearfix">
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is a Virtual Assistant (VA)?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    What is the COST OF OUR SERVICES?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
  <div class="faqQuestion">
    Why work with our VA?
  </div>
  <div class="faqContent closed">
      <p>
        Data
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```